# Android 12 resolution stretch

Tags: samsung, screen-resolution, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

So i bought an aftermarket display for my samsung note10+.
The edge screen is just cut down, so the actual display is less wide.
But it report back as the original display resolution.

Now the circle icons are a bit stretched upward and pushed from the sides:

[image]

If i set a smaller resolution width, it gives me black bars at the sides. I need to stretch the image to those black bars.
Any idea?